# variable replacement from external document using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, replace, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am trying to replace a variable `@mybook.01@` in source file with the values from properties.xml that matches the `book-name` element in source file with the `group id` in properties.xml

Here is my source file:

```
<books>
   <us-country-factory>
      <book-name>books/props/Classic</book-name>
      <store-property name="book1" type="java.lang.String">@mybook.01@</store-property>
      <store-property name="book2" type="java.lang.String">@mybook.01@</store-property>
      <store-property name="book2">CLIENT</store-property>
   </us-country-factory>
   <us-country-factory>
      <book-name>books/props/Classic1</book-name>
      <store-property name="book1" type="java.lang.String">@mybook.01@</store-property>
      <store-property name="book2" type="java.lang.String">@mybook.01@</store-property>
   </us-country-factory>   
</books>
```

and Here is my properties.xml file:

```
<variables>
    <group id="books/props/Classic">
        <variable id="book1">
            <mybook.01>123</mybook.01>
        </variable>
        <variable id="book2">
            <mybook.01>789</mybook.01>
        </variable>
    </group>
    <group id="books/props/Classic1">
        <variable id="book1">
            <mybook.01>ab2</mybook.01>
        </variable>
        <variable id="book2">
            <mybook.01>rt67</mybook.01>
        </variable> 
    </group>    
</variables>
```

So the Expected output would looks like this:

```
<books>
   <us-country-factory>
      <book-name>books/props/Classic</book-name>
      <store-property name="book1" type="java.lang.String">123</store-property>
      <store-property name="book2" type="java.lang.String">789</store-property>
   </us-country-factory>
   <us-country-factory>
      <book-name>books/props/Classic1</book-name>
      <store-property name="book1" type="java.lang.String">ab2</store-property>
      <store-property name="book2" type="java.lang.String">rt67</store-property>
   </us-country-factory>   
</books>
```

1. `book-nam`e in source.xml matches with `group id` from properties.xml
2. `store-property` name in source.xml matches with `variable id` from properties.xml
3. `@mybook.01@` from source.xml is replaced with value of `<mybook.01>` from properties.xml

I was able to get this when there is only group in properties.xml and one chile node, but not sure how to loop the groups with the matched templates.

Here is my xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="2.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="props" match="variable/*"
             use="concat(../@id,'&#xd;',name(.))"/>  
    <xsl:template match="book-name">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="store-property"/>
    </xsl:template>               
    <xsl:template match="store-property">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:variable name="id" select="@name"/>
            <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="@(.*?)@">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('props',concat($id,'&#xd;',regex-group(1)),
                            doc('properties.xml'))"/>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:non-matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <!--identity for all other nodes-->
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Suggestions please...

Comment: When i add additional child node `<store-property name="book2">CLIENT</store-property>` the code @Daniel provided is not outputing well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this instead...

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="props" select="document('properties.xml')"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="store-property[matches(.,'^@')]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$props/*/group[@id=current()/../book-name]/variable[@id=current()/@name]/*[local-name()=tokenize(current(),'@')[2]]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output** (using the supplied XML examples)

```
<books>
   <us-country-factory>
      <book-name>books/props/Classic</book-name>
      <store-property name="book1" type="java.lang.String">123</store-property>
      <store-property name="book2" type="java.lang.String">789</store-property>
      <store-property name="book2">CLIENT</store-property>
   </us-country-factory>
   <us-country-factory>
      <book-name>books/props/Classic1</book-name>
      <store-property name="book1" type="java.lang.String">ab2</store-property>
      <store-property name="book2" type="java.lang.String">rt67</store-property>
   </us-country-factory>
</books>
```

Comment: thanks for your help.. the code works. just out of curiocity wondering what is the diffrence between these two: `                    <xsl:value-of select="key('props',concat($id,'&#xd;',regex-group(1)), doc('properties.xml'))"/>` and 
                   ` <xsl:value-of select="$props/*/mq[@id=current()/../jndi-name]/variable[@id=current()/@name]/*[local-name()=tokenize(current(),'@')[2]]"/>
 `

Comment: @phani - Not much really. You could use either. Also, I modified the stylesheet to handle the update you made to the input XML. Right now the additional `store-property` is output. If you don't want it output, just add this template: `<xsl:template match="store-property"/>`

Comment: One thing that i noticed the diffrence between these two logics are: The one that i posted is also supporting other child node attributes, where as the following logic that you have provided is supporting only the child-node that has `store-name` in it. thanks and appreciate your help.